# Open DevMenu on conected OS-Device with laptop react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-cli

I want to open the DevMenu on my iPad (6. generation, iOS 14.5.1) with my Laptop (Windows)
when I run `npm start` (or `react-native start`, doesnt matter) it will start the development server and the iPad connects to it and downloads the bundle. The logs will show in the console on the laptop as well...
But as soon as I press "r" or "d" to reload or open DevMenu, I get the ever-occuring error message:

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Opening developer menu...
```

My iPad is on the same network and I can ping it through console. Additionally its connected with USB but I dont think this makes any difference. Also tested on an iPhone 8 (iOS 14.5.1)
PS: I also configured the bundler with the right ip and port
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you ever figure this out? I am having this issue now

Comment: No I think you need a MacBook for iOS and Android and Windows for only Android